# Error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i am trying to solve this problem by following all steps which is required to connect a Apache Wicket web application to MySQL database.

**step1** Right Click on project -> Build Path ->Configure Build Path -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab -> Add external jar -> then i browse MySql-Connector-5.0.8 jar file.

**step2**In program i write down

```
public static Connection con=null;
public static Connection getConnection()
{
    try
    {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");     
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1", "root", "root");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    catch(SQLException e){System.out.println(e);}
    finally{
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    return con;
}
```

but still facing Error the **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**
now what to do..I need your help

Comment: Check whether you have the `MySql-Connector-5.0.8.jar` under Libraries. If it not there might broken ref , try to add it with the project

Comment: yes it is under library..should i add the dependency for MySql in POM.xml..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention your project is a web application I assume that you also use an application server to run your application. **Make sure the driver jar is also available to the server.** Depending on the platform you may have to change some of the server's configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jar file and paste it into your project. It will run perfectively.

Comment: in which directory i should paste it..?because i have already add MySql jar in Library..

Comment: in lib folder in your project

Comment: the library is not looking like a folder, it looks like a rar file and i add my jar to library..

Comment: if you paste in lib folder then error will be go.i face this type of problems.

Comment: Not really enought detail to be considered a good answer. As the comments that follow show.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error by deploying mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar into your application's classpath. If you are not sure how to set CLASSPATH, follow instructions given in that article. Depending upon your build tool you can do following to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Eclipse, Maven and Gradle.

Read more: http://www.java67.com/2015/07/javalangclassnotfoundexception-com.mysql.jdbc.Driver-solution.html#ixzz5jp43It2X**strong text**